# Issues Rendering Rmarkdown PDF from second R script (Windows)

Tags: r, windows, r-markdown

I have successfully created a .rmd file and an associated Rscript that renders the .rmd. The goal of this set up is so that I can automatically create PDF reports by scheduling the .R file to run daily. On a Mac, the .R script works well and PDF files are successfully created.

However, on Windows, the .rmd file can be manually knitted (albeit, this is a slight variation of the automated .rmd file because all object values are explicitly defined), but the .R script causes a "LaTex failed to compile..." error.

Has anyone ran into similar issues in the past. Like I mentioned above, I have no issues with this set up on a Mac but need to transfer it to a Windows device.

Please let me know if you have any questions or would like additional information. I will paste 'sessionInfo()' from the Windows below.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] patchwork_1.1.2   data.table_1.14.4 DT_0.27           kableExtra_1.3.4  knitr_1.40        readxl_1.4.1      lubridate_1.9.0   timechange_0.1.1 
 [9] rmarkdown_2.18    forcats_0.5.2     stringr_1.4.1     dplyr_1.0.10      purrr_0.3.5       readr_2.1.3       tidyr_1.2.1       tibble_3.1.8     
[17] ggplot2_3.4.0     tidyverse_1.3.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] svglite_2.1.1       assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.30       utf8_1.2.2          R6_2.5.1            cellranger_1.1.0    backports_1.4.1     reprex_2.0.2       
 [9] evaluate_0.18       httr_1.4.4          pillar_1.8.1        rlang_1.0.6         googlesheets4_1.0.1 rstudioapi_0.14     labeling_0.4.2      webshot_0.5.4      
[17] googledrive_2.0.0   htmlwidgets_1.5.4   tinytex_0.45        munsell_0.5.0       broom_1.0.1         compiler_4.2.2      modelr_0.1.10       xfun_0.34          
[25] pkgconfig_2.0.3     systemfonts_1.0.4   htmltools_0.5.3     tidyselect_1.2.0    fansi_1.0.3         viridisLite_0.4.1   crayon_1.5.2        tzdb_0.3.0         
[33] dbplyr_2.2.1        withr_2.5.0         grid_4.2.2          jsonlite_1.8.3      gtable_0.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.3     DBI_1.1.3           magrittr_2.0.3     
[41] scales_1.2.1        cli_3.4.1           stringi_1.7.8       farver_2.1.1        fs_1.5.2            xml2_1.3.3          ellipsis_0.3.2      generics_0.1.3     
[49] vctrs_0.5.0         tools_4.2.2         glue_1.6.2          hms_1.1.2           fastmap_1.1.0       yaml_2.3.6          colorspace_2.0-3    gargle_1.2.1       
[57] rvest_1.0.3         haven_2.5.1
```

Here is a screenshot of the only abnormal message I get in the console when attempting to render the pdf with a separate R script. From the latex log a similar issue is evident (second image). I wonder if these can act as clues to help determine the issue.

Thank you!

[image: Here is a screenshot of the only abnormal message I get in the console when attempting to render the pdf with a separate R script]

[image]

Comment: @KJ Thanks for your help. I have looked in the local log (.txt file) and the reason does not seem to specify why the LaTex failed to compile. The only note of immediate interest is at the bottom where the log states " !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF produced!"

However, I can provide you with the full log if that would be helpful! 

It seems odd to me that I can knit a very similar file manually with no issues - however, using the R script causes this issue.

Comment: @KJ I have added a screenshot to the post. I wonder if this can provide a hint about the problem. This is the only abnormal message from the Console when running this script. 

Thank you for your help and patience on this. My apologies, however, the inner workings of Latex allude me so far!

Comment: @KJ Thanks again for your help and for the note regarding text rather than images.

The CMD prompt you have provided notes that pdflatex exists.

pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6.1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
... author information etc.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have narrowed in on the issue. That line is in the header-includes: section and reads " - \pretitle{\begin{centre}\LARGE\includegraphics[width=12cm]{image.jpg}\\[\bigskipamount]}  ".... The goal is to have this as a title page with a large image in the centre. All the alterations I make to this line result in a new, different error. Do you happen to have a suggestion as to what a better alternative strategy is?